# Rendering this pandoc table

Tags: pandoc

```
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Right         | Left          | Centered           |
+==============:+:==============+:==================:+
| Bananas       | $1.34         | built-in wrapper   |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

I used the standard command

```
pandoc test.txt -o test.pdf
```

But I get the above unrendered text. Am I doing something wrong here?

I am new to pandoc tables. Are grid tables fundamentally different than other tables supported by pandoc markdown?

Comment: If you format your table as code it will show up properly.

Comment: I see a difference between the seperator of Right | Left , and Left | Centered, maybe the syntax is wrong?

Comment: Matt Jones was right; I could render it better. Since I am a novice at `pandoc`, I expected a well rendered latex table like version in my pdf.

Comment: @user6716300 that table works fine on pandoc.org/try, so what's your exact question?

Comment: I think, I was trying to convert this pandoc grid table directly to pdf without converting it to LaTeX. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to render this adapted version in [stackedit.io](http://stackedit.io)

```
| Right         | Left          | Centered           |
|-:|:-|:-:|
| Bananas       | $1.34         | built-in wrapper   |
```

And your version in [pandoc/try](http://pandoc.org/try/?text=%2B---------------%2B---------------%2B--------------------%2B%0A%7C%20Right%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20Left%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20Centered%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%0A%2B%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3A%2B%3A%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%2B%3A%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3A%2B%0A%7C%20Bananas%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20%241.34%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20built-in%20wrapper%20%20%20%7C%0A%2B---------------%2B---------------%2B--------------------%2B&from=markdown&to=html4), which did work as expected. Try specifying the input and output format, and also try a different output format to see if that works.